# Problem with 2 variable PCA loadings- Loadings are the same for all variables

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm working on a problem for which i want to do some dimensionality reduction using 3 different PCAs of 2 variables each. Basically i want to perform a PCA and keep the first component between the pairs M.max-max.Z; M.min-min.Z; and P-N.
For this im executing the following code:

```
pca.min<-M.scaled%>%
  select(M.min, min.Z)%>%
  princomp()
  
pca.max<-M.scaled%>%
  select(M.max, max.Z)%>%
  princomp()

pca.NP<-M.scaled%>%
  select(N, P)%>%
  princomp()
```

My problem is that even though these variables are different, have different values between them, and are not highly correlated (except the min.Z-M.min pair which has a 0.74 correlation), when i ask for the PCA loading i get:

```
> pca.min$loadings

Loadings:
     Comp.1 Comp.2
M.min  0.707  0.707
min.Z -0.707  0.707

              Comp.1 Comp.2
SS loadings       1.0    1.0
Proportion Var    0.5    0.5
Cumulative Var    0.5    1.0
> pca.max$loadings

Loadings:
     Comp.1 Comp.2
M.max  0.707  0.707
max.Z  0.707 -0.707

              Comp.1 Comp.2
SS loadings       1.0    1.0
Proportion Var    0.5    0.5
Cumulative Var    0.5    1.0
> pca.NP$loadings

Loadings:
 Comp.1 Comp.2
N  0.707  0.707
P  0.707 -0.707

              Comp.1 Comp.2
SS loadings       1.0    1.0
Proportion Var    0.5    0.5
Cumulative Var    0.5    1.0
```

So they all have the same loading for each variable (0.707). When i do the biplots the proportion of explained variance by each component is different (not 0.5 as the $loadings shows), so my problem is not so much the explained variance by each component but rather the loading of each variable in the components being the same. I don't understant why this is happening. I am definitely not a PCA expert so this might be a rather obvious question to some, but its baffling me. I have tried using different PCA functions and it is the same.

PS. All data is previously centered and standardized.

Here are the scree plots for the 3 PCAs
[image]

[image]

[image]